# How to get my ArrayAdapter running?

Tags: java, android, android-layout, listview, android-arrayadapter

i'm just experiencing trouble with getting my Arrayadapter up and running with a List of Strings.
I just did many hours of research now and I got already another adapter running when i used the plain simple `android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1` with the Constructor
`ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getApplicationContext(), android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, stringList)`

This worked well when I used an empty layout file with nothing but the listView in it.
I now want to get another activity with a ListView but i allways get NullPointerException.

I want to insert TextItems into a List which is below a Relative Layout and beside some other stuff on my Layout. I already know i need to use this Constructor: `ArrayAdapter(Context context, int resource, int textViewResourceId)`

I tried many things and every example just looked simple but i couldn't adapt it to my work. Can you please help me to get this solved? Here is the relevant Code:

My Adapter in my Class:

```
ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getApplicationContext(), android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, R.id.logListView, stringList)
```

My Layout File:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context="com.example.tw.fuelcalc.DrivingLog">

    <ListView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:id="@+id/logListView"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textView13" />

    <Spinner
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/spinner"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textView14"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
        android:text="Medium Text"
        android:id="@+id/textView13"
        android:layout_below="@+id/spinner"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
        android:text="Medium Text"
        android:id="@+id/textView14"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

And my Error which drives me completely mad for days now:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
                                                                                    at android.widget.ArrayAdapter.createViewFromResource(ArrayAdapter.java:392)
                                                                                    at android.widget.ArrayAdapter.getView(ArrayAdapter.java:362)
                                                                                    at com.example.tobiaswiens.fuelcalc.DrivingLog$1.getView(DrivingLog.java:24)
                                                                                    at android.widget.AbsListView.obtainView(AbsListView.java:2627)
                                                                                    at android.widget.ListView.measureHeightOfChildren(ListView.java:1259)
```

I skipped some stuff in the error message, implicing this not interesting.

Many Thanks in advance, Tobias

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out that i messed up with the Constructor. i passed the ID for a TextView which was absolutely not on the simpleItem ressource. I created a Custom Layout with a Textview under a relative Layout and it worked as it should.

Maybe this is helpful to somebody.